# If we count Avogadro's Number of stars that are closest to Earth, how big that space would be?

Tags: star, distances

I think that the answer to this question will be useful as a scale to appreciate the size of the universe.

So, **If we count Avogadro's Number of stars that are closest to Earth, how big that space would be?** And how many galaxies/clusters will be engulfed in that space? And for a start, let's just consider only three dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by "only three dimensions"?

Comment: @HDE226868: If one considers time as the 4th dimension, there may be closer stars to Earth in the past and future.

Comment: But do we consider that dimension when talking about, say, the size of a galaxy?

Comment: @HDE226868 Of course not. It was there so that the question may not become too broad, for people who are interested about too much detail, like me.

Comment: By the way, I started following Scientific Imagination a while ago!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's going to be all (or perhaps *nearly* all) of the observable Universe. Roughly speaking, there are [several hundred billion stars](http://science.howstuffworks.com/milky-way5.htm) in the Milky Way. And extrapolating the number of galaxies in deep Hubble images suggests [something like](http://www.space.com/25303-how-many-galaxies-are-in-the-universe.html) a hundred billion galaxies in the observable Universe.  Put these together and [you get about](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Herschel/How_many_stars_are_there_in_the_Universe) $10^{22}$ to $10^{24}$ stars in the observable Universe.  Avogadro's number is $6.022\times 10^{23}$, which is in the upper end of that range.  So, given current estimates, you'd need at least most, if not all, of the observable Universe to get $N_A$ stars.